# How do I make a battle sequence count the enemy's health down?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a battle sequence against a wizard for a project in my game development class. It should just be a simple "when enemy's health is zero, proceed", "when player's health is zero, game over" sequence.

I have the sequence itself down, but there's an issue with the HP. I have tried to move the if statements for the player and enemy's HP over and over, into different functions, places in and before the while loop in wizardAttack(), but nothing.

```
import time
playerHealth = 15
wizardHealth = 15
inventory = ['Help Potion', 'Help Potion', 'Poison Dart', 'Dagger', 'Torch']
print('Your HP:', playerHealth)
print('Wizard\'s HP:', wizardHealth)
time.sleep(3)
if playerHealth <= 0:
    print('The wizard is too strong! You black out and get dragged back to your dungeon.')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('Game Over')
    playAgain()
if wizardHealth <= 0:
        print('The wizard goes down with a THUD! You win the battle!')
        time.sleep(4)
        print('On the wizard\'s body, you notice a dagger and take it.')
        time.sleep(4)
        inventory.append('Dagger')
        twowizards()
```

What should happen is the health of both the player and the wizard should tick down, and when one character's health equals 0, then the battle should end properly and move on to the next sequence, or a game over should the enemy win. What happens in reality is the health more or less resets to 15 and it gets me nowhere.

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. The biggest problem is that this code won't run since lines 6 and 7 will throw NameErrors.

Comment: When is the battle actually happening ? I don't see any statement where the characters' health is being reduced, so I don't see how the code within the `if` conditions could be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have not created a battle sequence. maybe something like:

```
import time
import random
playerHealth = 15
wizardHealth = 15
inventory = ['Help Potion', 'Help Potion', 'Poison Dart', 'Dagger', 'Torch']
print('Your HP:', playerHealth)
print('Wizard\'s HP:', wizardHealth)
time.sleep(3)
if 'Dagger' in inventory:
  playerDamage = 4
while playerHealth >=1 and wizardHealth >=1:
  wizardDamage = random.randint(1,5)
  playerHealth -= wizardDamage
  print("You bash the wizard, dealing "+str(playerDamage)+" damage!")
  time.sleep(2)
  wizardHealth -= playerDamage
  print("The wizard bashes you, dealing "+str(wizardDamage)+" damage!")
  time.sleep(2)

if playerHealth <= 0:
    print('The wizard is too strong! You black out and get dragged back to your dungeon.')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('Game Over')
    playAgain()
if wizardHealth <= 0:
        print('The wizard goes down with a THUD! You win the battle!')
        time.sleep(4)
        print('On the wizard\'s body, you notice a dagger and take it.')
        time.sleep(4)
        inventory.append('Dagger')
        twowizards()
```

Some of your functions are still not defined, though.